# Ways to compare keys from json dump with python

Tags: python, json, algorithm

I am newbie to programming ,need some inputs/direction to build a smart code.

I have 10 ec2 instances, each instance have a Tag which contains a dictionary of 3 key/val pairs. Some instances have same keys and may be few have different key,I want to find out  which instances have different keys within the Tag. 
Comparing every key with rest 9 instances's keys is not the best way to go I think. 
Please let me how to approach this issue and do I need to use json dumper to parse the data?

Here is the example of a single instance, I have 10 of these.

```
"tags": [
            {
                "depid": 18,
                "key": "sales",
                "value": "31"
            },
            {
                "depid": 239,
                "key": "eng",
                "value": "steve"
            },
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you're trying to solve. What is `depid` short for? What's the meaning of those three key/value pairs? Why are you comparing keys?

Comment: Nothing interesting came to mind so far

Comment: These are actually ec2 instances and out of  hundreds of them I need to figure out which instances doesn't have the correct tag values.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you were looking for?

```
data = {'tags': [{'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'},
                 {'key': 'key2', 'value': 'value2'}]}
keys = set([tag['key'] for tag in data['tags']])
required_keys = set(['key1', 'key2'])
print keys == required_keys    # check whether matches exactly
print keys >= required_keys    # check whether contains all required keys
```